Invalid bundle - on iPad, you need to include the Main.storyboard launch storyboard file in your bundle
I have Created one application for mobile using flutter.
I uploaded app for google play platform successfully.
After that I uploaded app for iPhone AppStore through Xcode it gives error like belove
"Invalid bundle. Because your app supports Multitasking on iPad, you need to include the Main.storyboard launch storyboard file in your bundle. Use UILaunchScreen instead if the app’s MinimumOSVersion is 14 or higher and you prefer to configure the launch screen without storyboards. For details, see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uilaunchstoryboardname (ID: - - -)"
I am not able to solve this issue.
So, I just remove iPad option from Xcode and public only for iPhone device.

See Invalid Bundle Error - "requires launch storyboard"
